# How to select item from drop down menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, cypress

I'm doing an automatic test in Cypress and I have a problem catching the first checkbox in the drop down menu box:

[image]

And the code what I tried:

```
 cy.get('.dx-texteditor-container', { timeout: 5000 }).eq(3).click().eq(0)
                    .within(() => {
                        cy.wait(500);
                        cy.get('.dx-list-select-all-label', { timeout: 5000 }).should('be.visible')
                            .click();
                    })
```

The code itself looks like this:

[image: code]

I've been catching it for a few days now and nothing yet. Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this opens the dropdown:

```js
 cy.get('.dx-texteditor-container', { timeout: 5000 }).eq(3).click()
```

After this you can write:

```js
cy.contains('.dx-list-select-all-label', 'Vybrat vše').should('be.visible').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be trying to click the label instead of the checkbox.

The checkbox is usually an input of type checkbox like:

```html
<input type="checkbox" ...>
```

And from your picture, it should be right besides your label inside that `div` here:
[image]

And something like that should do:

```js
cy.get('div.dx-list-select-all-checkbox').find('input[type=checkbox]').check({ force: true })
```

I added `{ force: true }` because in many web framework, the input of type checkbox is hidden behind divs to make styling easier. You may not need it.
See `check()` docs [here](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/check).